# Issue with Viewing Android App on Google Play Store

Tags: android, maui, google-play-console

I have created a organisation only app on Google Play Console, filled out all relavent information in the App Content area, added the correct emails to the 'Internal app sharing' email list and created a release and uploaded my .aab to the production track and closed testing track.

Once the .aab has been accepted and the upload process completed I waited 24 hours incase any warning messages or errors occurred.

After 24 hours I reviewed the 'Pre-launch report' which had no errors or problems.

I then go to the 'App bundle explorer' and navigate to the 'Downloads' area and copy this link:[image: Internal app sharing link]

Which I then use on my android device, which takes me to this screen:
[image: Screenshot from link result]

When I use the 'Open In Play Store' button the Play Store Application is opened and I am greeted with a never ending loading screen, I have left this for a hour just incase I was being inpatient but nothing happened.

The next thing I tried was to add the application to the private app area in the Google Admin Console:
[image: Admin Console Application]

As you can see here there is another link to 'View In Google Play' but upon using this link on the android device I am met with this screen:

[image: Admin Console Google Play link result]

I have tried to use both links on all allowed emails in the organisation but nothing has worked.

Am I missing something in either area? Is there something I need to do in the play store that allows certain apps to be downloaded by organisation members? Nothing in all of the Google Documentation points to anything like this that I have found.

Note: I have tried all the process on two difference devices, both had internal sharing turned on.

Comment: I am vague on Android's "internal app" review process, but it sounds like Google owes you one more email, saying that it is ready in the store. If you don't get such an email in another 24 hours, I would contact their support. The FIRST time you define an app, the delay might be longer than subsequent times.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I did all of this on Wednesday 1st around 13:00 so I would hope that I would have had a email through by now stating that. If any changes are made I do get one through stating 'Your updating is live in the store' which would indicate again that the application is ready in the store. Happy to give it another 24 hours, something may come through, fingers crossed! I've read elsewhere that the first time you create a app it can take longer too so there may be something there too.

Comment: ok, that was the email I meant. Should work within a few hours of that email. Otherwise, support will have to investigate.